# Meaning of the notation $\sigma_{ji,j}$

Tags: tensor-calculus, differentiation, notation, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

In page 28 of the book *Introduction to Linear Elasticity, 4ed* by Phillip L. Gould · Yuan Feng, it says
$$
\int_V{\left( f_i+\sigma _{ji,j} \right) \text{d}V=0}
$$
What does it mean by writing $\sigma _{ji,j}$?

Also in equation $(2.32)$,
$$
\int_V{G_{i,i}\text{d}V=\int_A{n_iG_i\text{d}A}}
$$
What does $G_{i,i}$ means?

[image]

Comment: Possibly tensor notation: http://www.continuummechanics.org/tensornotationbasic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, Einstein's summation convention is a notation shortcut in which repeated indices are summed over. The comma that follows the physical quantities you have mentioned is just **partial derivation** with respect to the $i^{\text{th}}$ coordinate of whatever system coordinate you are working in. The only resources I have seen this comma notation used are GR books and articles, but it is obvious that this is also the case here.

Thus, in your case, $G_{i,i}= \dfrac{\partial G_i}{\partial x^i} \equiv \sum_i \dfrac{\partial G_i}{\partial x^i} \equiv \nabla \cdot G,$
the divergence of your vector field $G$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation above (2.30) in your question looks like a Stokes' theorem, which is why I'm assuming $G_{i,j} = \frac{ d G_{i}}{dx^{j}}$. The $,j$ just means take a derivative with respect to the $j$-th coordinate.

Comment: Are you familiar with Einstein's summation convention?

Comment: Sure, but the equation was about the meaning of the comma. I have edited my answer to be a little more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Einstein summation convention, a repeated index in a term signifies summation over that index.

Comment: Yeah, but the repeated indices are on different variables, not on the same one. Usually. $a_ib^i $ means sumation over i but $a_{ii}$ does not mean a sumation. It's just one component of a matrix or tensor. Also $a_{i,i}$ does not mean sumation over i.

Comment: @nasu In the case of $a_{i,i}$, it sure does.  That is the divergence of the vector a.

Comment: @nasu And, for the cartesian components of the tensor $a_{ij}$, $a_{ii}$ is the trace of the tensor.